# Blob Created event only after Blob committed?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

We have set up a Azure Function with an eventHubTrigger to read blobs created by Apache Nifi. The EventGridSchema is filtered for Blob Created events, largely working fine. The problem is that the Azure Function occasionally fetches the blob before it is fully committed.

Storage account is of type BlockBlobStorage with Hierarchical namespace. The StorageBlobLogs shows that the typical sequence of operations:

Nifi processor: `CreatePathFile` > `AppendFile` > `FlushFile`.
Followed by the Azure Function doing `Getblob` > `DeleteBlob`. When the problem occurs, the GetBlob operation happens prior to `FlushFile` or even prior to `AppendFile`

It seems that only the CreatePathFile operation trigges Blob Created events. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) indicates that FlushWithClose would also trigger it, and we have tried applying an event filter on `data.api` without achieving anything other than stopping function runs altogether.

How can we setup a subscription for Blob Created Event triggered strictly after the Blob has been fully committed?

Comment: I have no idea how Nifi works, but does "CreateFilePath" maybe already create an (empty) blob?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to create an empty file first. [Nifi processor docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.12.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.PutAzureDataLakeStorage/additionalDetails.html)

But what is the implication?

Comment: well, even an empty blob rightfully triggers a Blob Created event.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I was expecting one Blob Create event for every (empty) blob created which I would be filtered out and one for every fully committed blob that would trigger the Function, but observe only the former one.

Comment: it's logical, isn't it? The blob only gets created once. Afterwards you just update it, so ofc there is no other "created" event

Comment: Maybe, from the docs linked my initial post it says: 

_Specifically, this event is triggered when clients use the CreateFile and FlushWithClose operations that are available in the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API._

So I was expecting two Created Events for each blob...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How can we setup a subscription for Blob Created Event triggered strictly after the Blob has been fully committed?*

There is no configuration as it depends upon which operation your client is using for in the blob REST API.
The same is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#blob-storage-events) for the Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated created when it is fired.

> Triggered when a blob is created or replaced. Specifically, this event
> is triggered when clients use the PutBlob, PutBlockList, or CopyBlob
> operations that are available in the Blob REST API and when the Block
> Blob is completely committed. If clients use the CopyBlob operation on
> accounts that have the hierarchical namespace feature enabled on them,
> the CopyBlob operation works a little differently. In that case, the
> Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated event is triggered when the CopyBlob
> operation is initiated and not when the Block Blob is completely
> committed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, when using the DataLakeFileClient Upload method, you need to pass in options with [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.models.datalakefileuploadoptions.close?view=azure-dotnet) = true in order for the FlushAndClose event to be fired, otherwise its just doing Flush at the end. Without setting this property I only saw the CreateFile in data.api and the filter would remove that and not have the FlushAndClose

Copied from current documentation on close property.

> Azure Storage Events allow applications to receive notifications when files change. When Azure Storage Events are enabled, a file changed event is raised. This event has a property indicating whether this is the final change to distinguish the difference between an intermediate flush to a file stream and the final close of a file stream. The close query parameter is valid only when the action is "flush" and change notifications are enabled. If the value of close is "true" and the flush operation completes successfully, the service raises a file change notification with a property indicating that this is the final update (the file stream has been closed). If "false" a change notification is raised indicating the file has changed. The default is false. This query parameter is set to true by the Hadoop ABFS driver to indicate that the file stream has been closed.